# boost::this_thread::sleep_for() put all my threads to sleep

Tags: c++, thread-sleep

```
void WINEvents::loop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(500));

        //boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));

        /*boost::mutex                   mutex;
        boost::condition_variable_any    condition;
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mutex);
        condition.wait_for(lock, boost::chrono::milliseconds(500));*/
    }
}

void SDLplateforme::execute()
{
    WINEvents winEvents;
    boost::thread newThread(WINEvents::loop, &winEvents);

    while (true)
    {
        #####EDIT:
        auto time = Int2String(_timer->getTicks());
        SDL_SetWindowTitle(_window, time.c_str());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto plateforme = make_shared<SDLplateforme>();

    boost::thread mainThread(SDLplateforme::execute, plateforme);
    mainThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I creates two threads:

- `SDLplateforme::execute()` -> constantly displaying timer value in the window frame
- `WINEvents::loop()` -> is put to sleep using `boost::this_thread::sleep`

But, it appears the sleep call in `WINEvents::loop()` also make the other thread asleep, since the text is displayed with interval equal to the sleep parameter (here 500ms), whereas it is supposed to be updated every frame.

Is `boost::this_thread::sleep()` supposed to sleep only the current thread?
If yes, what do I do wrong? If no, how do I achieve that?

Comment: There is **no** way to make the other thread sleep by any API, you can only put the caller thread to sleep. Most likely, by putting one thread to sleep, you are affecting the other one through messages, shared resources, etc.

Comment: `sleep` and its variants should only affect the thread that calls it. But (just guessing) if that thread is running the UI's event loop, the loop won't process any input or output messages while it's sleeping, so the UI won't change until the thread wakes up.

Comment: So it is supposed to work, but, here, printRandomText2Screen() is just displaying the FPS count, and it doesn't have any interactions with I/O events ...

Comment: I replaced everything in my main loop with just SDL_SetWindowTitle(), displaying the timer value, so it does not use anything in my engine. And still the window title is updated every "sleep param" ms ...

Comment: OK, the SDL_PollEvent() that process the window events, actually have to be within the same thread than the one where you declared the window for it to work ... so you can't untie the SDL_PollEvent() frequency with the window's refresh rate ... -> it was the window's refresh rate, not my engine ...